# Are Restriction Enzymes obsolete with CRISPR?

Tags: crispr

Are Restriction Enzymes obsolete with CRISPR?

Answer (score 1):

No.

While CRISPR allows you cut a piece of DNA anywhere, you need to order a guide RNA to target your desired cut site. All standard plasmids still carry traditional restriction sites, and it's often convenient to use these. Using CRISPR as a restriction enzyme is probably more expensive and more complicated than using traditional restriction digest. Additionally, there are limitations about PAM sites with CRISPR. And you can always PCR a plasmid using whatever primers you want to produce a blunt end product that is "cut" where ever you want, and I'd bet the DNA oligos needed for PCR are cheaper than the guide RNA you need for CRISPR.